# start page in center on first boot ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Using react,
I created a page that can be represented by a 3x3 vector.
I want that when the page loads it shows the screen that is in the position
2x2, each part of the vector is a canvas.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried react-router-dom, I tried to assign values ​​to window.screenX. 
I also tried using the window.addEventListener(" DOMContentLoaded ", ()=>{          
   window.scrollTo()  }) but I don't know why scrollTo doesn't run.

Comment: I suggest you add what you've tried to your question, and explain where it falls short of what you're trying to achieve. That way you'll be closer to the guidelines for a "good question".

Answer (score 0):

i got it using this code!!

```html
import React,{useRef, useLayoutEffect} from "react";

export default  function Home(){
  const loadRef = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const element = loadRef.current;
    screen.loadTop = element.offsetTop;
    screen.loadLeft = element.offsetLeft;
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     window.scrollTo({ top: screen.loadTop, left: screen.loadLeft, 
                  behavior: 'smooth' })
           })
  })
  return (
    <div ref={loadRef} className="container"/>
  )
}
```